# Setting the correct Axios path after deployment to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I've created a simple TODO list application using MERN stack, and it works find locally. I have deployed it to Heroku and the react page loads up, but it doesn't connect to my MongoDB database.

It seems like since my axios code is set to localhost it is not getting the information from the database. I belive there is a way to set it so that instead of localhost it retrieves the correct url, but i don't know how to do that.

Thank you.

```
axios.get("localhost:5000/user")
```

Comment: you'll need to provide much more details, your mongodb connection logic, errors and logs where relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can use "/" instead of localhost:5000 axios will send request to the current base url.